# Pandas Not Enforcing Data Types

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge three CSV files. I can get them to merge just fine but I get `NaN` values in empty cells (see phone_number cells below). This would be okay, except when I loop over the rows and get an empty cell it says it's a `float`??? I don't understand because I specifically set the type to `str`.

```
      business_id                                         name                         address                  city state postal_code   latitude   longitude  phone_number
0       PR0001109             ST. BARNABAS SENIOR CENTER OF LA            675 S CARONDELET ST            LOS ANGELES    CA       90057  34.059267 -118.281234  213-388-4444
1       PR0001209                       COCO FRESH TEA & JUICE    11301 W OLYMPIC BLVD STE 105           LOS ANGELES    CA       90064  34.038185 -118.441811  626-319-5570
2       PR0001212                                  BOTTOM LINE          2066 W MANCHESTER AVE            LOS ANGELES    CA       90047  33.959802 -118.315636           NaN
3       PR0001671                                      TIKI TI             4427 W SUNSET BLVD            LOS ANGELES    CA       90027  34.097470 -118.285736           NaN
```

According to documentation I shouldn't be seeing this with the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myfile, dtype={'phone_number': str}, na_values=[''], keep_default_na=False)
```

However, this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Note: Using pandas version 0.23.4

Comment: It works as designed. For ints, there is no way to represent missing values (every possible value represents a number). Floats have more flexibility, so whenever you have NaNs in a numeric column it will be converted to float.

Comment: You don't have a column called `code` in your example? You have a `postal_code` but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `NaN` will in any case be interpreted as a float. What you can do however is use `result.fillna('')` a posteriori if the parameter `na_values` is not recognizing the empty cells as`NaN` and thus replacing them with `''`. Also, try this see if it works for you:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myfile, dtype={'code': str}, na_values=[], keep_default_na=False)
```